# Ember-cli get relative path of a dependency

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a unique issue that I can't get out because of how ember works with the dependencies.
I am using this lib to check a phone number : https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input/#utilities-script

And it's working fine, until that I have to set the relative path of a file call util.js like this to make some options works:

```
 $phoneInput.intlTelInput({
                    allowExtensions: false,
                    autoFormat: true,
                    autoHideDialCode: false,
                    nationalMode: false,
                    utilsScript: "/bower_components/intl-tel-input/lib/libphonenumber/build/utils.js"
                });
```

As you can see I tried to use `/bower_components/intl-tel-input/lib/libphonenumber/build/utils.js` but it can't find it. I also tried to add `assets/` or `../bower_...` but nothing is working, and I'm afraid this is not possible.

I did import the file in my Brocfile.js :

`app.import('bower_components/intl-tel-input/lib/libphonenumber/build/utils.js');`

And I can see it perfectly in the source.

Is there is a way to know the relative path of a dependency ?

I forgot to precise that I am initializing intlTelInput from a view within `didInsertElement`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you aren't able to refer the util file because it is not getting copied into the dist folder which the dev server serves.

There are 2 ways to get the file copied into the dist folder.

1. Put the `util.js` into the `public` folder. The contents of the public folder are copied as it is into the `dist` folder. Then you should be able to refer it's path the same way you refer images or fonts.
2. Use the `broccoli-funnel` and `broccoli-merge-trees` plugin.

Use npm to install both the packages.

```
npm install --save-dev broccoli-funnel
npm install --save-dev broccoli-merge-trees
```

In you `Brocfile.js`

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var app = new EmberApp();

var funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');

var utilFile = funnel('vendor', {
  srcDir: 'intl-tel-input-master/lib/libphonenumber/build',
  destDir: 'lib/intl-tel-input-master'
});

//module.exports = app.toTree();
module.exports = mergeTrees([app.toTree(), utilFile]);
```

I have copied the phone library into my `vendor` folder. So I am using broccoli-funnel to select the util.js file and broccoli-merge-trees to copy the file into the dist folder.

Now the util file should be accessible to ur plugin.